# Can I use the range method as a class with the jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that will have input fields added dynamically via JavaScript. Because I don't know about all of the fields beforehand, I can't define a range restriction like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [13, 23]
    }
  }
});
```

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range#range

For most validation methods, such as required, I have been adding validation method names as classes like this:

```
<input type="text" name="text_2" class="required">
```

Is it possible for me to use range in the same way that I've used required above? Or do I need to create a new method with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

If your input name is `text_2` be sure to update that in your rules like so

```
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
text_2: {
  required: true,
  range: [13, 23]
 }
}
});
```

or just change your input with the required field

```
<input type="text" name="text_2" class="required" range="13,23" />
```

Comment: That's not really feasible if text_2 may not be there, and I may have text_1 through text_200 depending on the user's actions. Is there a better way to abstract this?

Comment: Did you write that comment before I edited my answer? I updated it with something you can just add to the input itself.

Comment: Btw, check out the source on this page for more ways of implementing validation: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: <input type="text" name="text_2" class="required" range="13,23" />

Doesn't work in any of my pages. Did you find an example of it anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

The current version of jQuery validate respects the min and max attributes of the element so you can have a non-required input with range restrictions like this:

```
<input type="text" name="text_2" class="number" min="13" max="23" />
```